# Remove the header line returned by kubectl command

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using kubernetes, and I want to get podname from the app name. Here is the command I use.

```
POD=$(kubectl get pods -l app=influxdb-local -o custom-columns=:metadata.name -n influx)
```

Then I would like to use the result in:

```
kubectl exec -it -n influx $POD -- influx -username user -password "user" -execute "CREATE DATABASE db"
```

but the first line is empty, and the second line contains pod name, so the second command doesn't work.

How should I remove the first white line ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `--no-headers` to skip the header line

```
kubectl get pods -l app=influxdb-local -o custom-columns=:metadata.name -n influx --no-headers
```

## Custom Columns

Using the flag `-o custom-columns=<header-name>:<field>` will let you customize the output.

Example with resource name, under header `NAME`

```
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:metadata.name
```

output

```
NAME
myapp-5b77df6c48-dbvnh
myapp-64d5985fdb-mcgcn
httpd-9497b648f-9vtbl
```

**Empty header name:** you used the flag as `-o custom-columns=:metadata.name` - the first line is the header line, but with an empty header.

### Omit headers

the proper solution to omit the header line is by using the flag `--no-headers`

```
kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:metadata.name --no-headers
```

Example output

```
myapp-5b77df6c48-dbvnh
myapp-64d5985fdb-mcgcn
httpd-9497b648f-9vtbl
```

Comment: Is there a way to force kubernetes to print out headers ? I want to see the output with headers

Comment: Omit the `--no-headers` flag?